# How to add post method in to a link in ofbiz?

Tags: security, post, hyperlink, ofbiz

I'm using ofbiz framework to develop. But I'm confused with method of a link tag. Because security reasons, I don't want to display value of parameter in address of addressbar. In fact, I'm usually use method="post" for a a tag, but in ofbiz I don't know what attribute can do it. How can I do in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

My resolution is:

I use a `form` element instead of using a `link` element because forms use `post` as the default method:

If my link element is:

```
<link target="myTarget">
    <parameter param-name="myParameter" from-field="myField"/>
</link>
```

My form element will be:

```
<form name="myForms" type="single" target="myTarget">
    <field name="myField" parameter-name="myParameter">
        <hidden></hidden>
    </field>
    <field name="mySubmitButton" title="${uiLabelMap.myButtonTitle}">
        <submit button-type="button"/>
    </field>
</form>
```